# How can I tell if a user's MS Entourage 2008 (Mac OS X) has been patched to use EWS

Tags: macos, entourage, office-for-mac, microsoft-office-2008

I have a Mac desktop install of MS Office 2008 that's experiencing problems connecting to an Exchange 2007 server. Is there an easy way that I can determine from the desktop files alone if the owner has updated their copy of Entourage with the latest patch from Microsoft to convert its connection to the server to use Exchange Web Services (EWS)?

Entourage's About information reports that it's version 12.2.1, but I believe that this version corresponds to the last overall MS Office patch level, and not the EWS patch.

Anyone know?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if possible, you/your user should try ditching Entourage and use Mail & iCal. The Exchange support that came with Snow Leopard makes this a viable option. I'm much happier without Entourage.

Comment: Unfortunatley, Snow Leopard isn't an option. The desktop platform in question is PPC based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EWS is 13.0.0, and the About box will clearly say Web Services Edition.  You're looking at the previous version.